# How to call child function from parent button click in react and pass data to child function

Tags: reactjs

child Function

```
const addNewData = (dataFfromParent) => {
    append(dataFfromParent)
  };
```

parent component

```
const onButtonClick= () => {
  addNewData({id:1, name:'sam'})
}
``
```

Comment: What's your use-case scenario? Have you tried any code yet?

Comment: [Call child's function from a Parent component in React](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/react-call-function-in-child-component)

Comment: I think this is an anti-pattern in React. You can work with React or against React and your life will be much easier if you work WITH React. If you describe your use-case, I'm sure there is a better alternative.